# SED - Find and replace with special characters (#, , % )

Tags: command-line, files, sed, awk, grep

I'm aware that this is a really simple question, but I'm struggling to find a solution to this  .

I need to automatically find and replace in the `/etc/aliases` file the following section:

```
# Person who should get root's mail
#root:   marc
```

And it needs to look something like:

```
# Person who should get root's mail
root:  someone@something.tld
```

And I haven't been able to find a solution. Can you guys jump in with some suggestions? Doesn't need to be `sed`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a GNU system, you can use this:

```
sed -i '/^#[[:blank:]]Person/{n;s/#root:[[:blank:]]\+marc/root:\tsomeone@something.tld/;}' file
```

It searches for a line beginning with `# Person`. Then switches to the next line and replaces `#root:<blanks>marc` with `root:<tab> ...`. The `-i` flag edits the file inplace.

`-i`, `\+` and `\t` are GNU extensions. The standard equivalent of `\+` is the wordier `\{1,\}`. To edit the file in place portably, you'd need to resort to a temporary file. The standard equivalent of `\t` is to insert a tab character literally.